# Is it necessary to use graphics card VGA port for moniter when using a graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, vga, nvidia-graphics-card

I am getting Gefore GTX N560 Ti Hawk and saw that it doesn't have a VGA cable, I have always used the graphics card VGA port instead of motherboard inbuilt port when ever I use a graphics card. So is it necessary that I get a VGA to HDMI converter and Is there any performance difference?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question...you can use any of the ports on your GPU. You may need to get an adapter cable depending on what exact combination of ports your monitor and GPU have, but you'll need to add exact model numbers to work that out.

Answer (score 1):

Most motherboards will disable their onboard VGA ports once a dedicated graphics card has been fitted.

The connection you're referring to, [VGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) is an analog connection for VDUs, which has now been superseded by [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface), [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) and [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) as the commonly used connectors for graphics, all of which now carry a digital signal (in some cases, also an analog one).

The likely situation is that the graphics card you're getting uses DVI-I, most likely Dual Link. This interface supports analog, and as such, you can use an adapter to plug a VDU supporting only VGA into a DVI connection. You can check if your DVI connector is compatible with VGA by checking if it matches a DVI-I or DVI-A connector like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DVI_Connector_Types.svg) (The flat blade with 4 pins to the left of the image are required for the analog connection)